# No PDF produced with tikzexternalize when using llncs.sty documentclass

Tags: tikz-external, lncs

I am writing with the llncs documentclass and I want to externalize my tikz figures. It really is the combination that doesn't work; I can write in llncs fine without externalization, and I can externalize my tikz figures fine when using e.g. article documentclass.

I have a texlive 2014 installation in Linux under my home directory, and I've installed the llncs documentclass under ~/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lncs.

As a sample code, consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{llncs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikzcache/]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I look at a log file generated, e.g. document-figure0.log, it looks like the following:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2014.8.15)  6 OCT 2014 10:49
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\def\tikzexternalrealjob{document}\input{document}
(./document.tex

! LaTeX Error: File `llncs.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.2 ^^M

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 13 strings out of 495028
 267 string characters out of 6181497
 45944 words of memory out of 5000000
 3319 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 11i,0n,7p,88b,8s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: The problem seems to be with the option of `\tikzexternalize`. I'm able to compile when I remove it.

Comment: Yes, this is as I said. Seperately they work fine. It is the combination that fails.

Comment: I mean without `[prefix=tikzcache/]`

Comment: Dear Guido, that still does not work for me. I suspect including [prefix=tikzcache/] will also work for you, provided you make the directory first.

Comment: yes, it works for me

Comment: You should **not** install files under `~/texlive/2014/`. Either use `~/texlive/texmf-local/` or use `~/texmf`. If you use the former, you need to run `mktexlsr ~/texlive/texmf-local` afterwards. If you use the latter, you do not. Either way, create the subdirectory `tex/latex/lncs`. If you continue to have problems, please post a link to the class. (All I could find on ctan was http://ctan.org/pkg/llncs209.)

Comment: Dear cfr. I don't have a folder ~/texmf. Should it be there by default?

Comment: Dear cfr, I installed it now under ~/texlive/texmf-local and ran the mktexlsr command as you suggested. Still, it did not work. I have now, however, discovered that if I run the exact same command in the terminal (as reported by my texstudio editor) everything works fine!!

Comment: Can you check if pdflatex has the abillity to make external PDFs, i.e. how do you call pdflatex in the command line? You need to add -shell-escape. If I run pdflatex without this it also fails and doesn't produce PDFs of the Tikz figures.